# How to remember checkbox state when default state is checked?

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a form with a check box.

The check box has three "states":

1. Checked as default.
2. Unchecked by user.
3. Checked *again* by user.

How would I do something like that? If I use `!isset()`, I can uncheck the checkbox but it doesn't distinguish if it was unchecked by the user or if it's suppose to be checked as default.

I want to use this to refill  the last values of the form inputs whenever there are form errors on submit.

It's easy to do when the default state of the check box is unchecked. I can then just do:

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) echo ' checked'; //check box has been checked
```

Comment: To PHP, there's only two states: checked and unchecked.

Comment: PHP is more of a server-side scripting language. You might want to use a client-side language, like JavaScript, to handle the states. Your JavaScript can handle the state changes, and send them to the server for PHP processing.

Comment: A checkbox only has 2 states. Even to JavaScript, "default" is the same as when the user checks. JavaScript/PHP/[any web language] follow the same reasoning. If you want a "default state", I suggest making an array with default values of your form, pull any user data and overwrite those values and then use that as the current state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest way of maintaining the form's state after submission is to use an array to store the input values. First you set the default values, then if the form has been submitted, overwrite the defaults with whatever was submitted. In the HTML form, always output the value from the form array.

```
// create the array (for both viewing the form and maintaining the submitted values)
$form = array(
    'myCheckbox' => true // default to checked
    'firstName' => '',
)

// was the form submitted?
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    // overwrite the form array
    $form['myCheckbox'] = isset($_POST['myCheckbox']);
    $form['firstName'] = $_POST['firstName'];

    // at this point do any validation, if it fails, let the form show
}
```

Now for the form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="1" <?php echo $form['myCheckbox'] ? 'checked' : '' ?> />
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($form['firstName']); ?>" />
</form>
```

In the above, I added a text input `firstName` to illustrate that all of the form inputs should be managed by the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript with an input hidden to tell how many times the checkbox was clicked

```
<form action="">
<input id="bike" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" checked onchange="document.getElementById('bike-state').value=parseInt(document.getElementById('bike-state').value)+1">I have a bike
<input type="hidden" id="bike-state" name="count" value="0">
</form>
```

now in the server side if $_POST['bike-state'] is an odd then it was unchecked, if it is even and greater than 0 it was unchecked and then rechecked , otherwise if still 0 it was checked by default